# Next.js Scripts Error: Cannot find module '../../webpack-runtime.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, next.js, webpack-5

I want to create RSS script using Next.js.

So I put up a script in a subfolder inside the root folder `scripts/` & named it `build-rss.js`

## next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
    webpack: (config, options) => {
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.svg$/,
            issuer: { and: [/\.(js|ts|md)x?$/] },
            use: [
                {
                    loader: '@svgr/webpack',
                    options: {
                        prettier: false,
                        svgo: true,
                        svgoConfig: { plugins: [{ removeViewBox: false }] },
                        titleProp: true,
                    },
                },
            ],
        })

        if (!options.dev && options.isServer) {
            const originalEntry = config.entry

            config.entry = async () => {
                const entries = { ...(await originalEntry()) }
                entries['./scripts/build-rss'] = './scripts/build-rss.js'
                return entries
            }
        }

        if (!options.isServer) {
            config.resolve.fallback.fs = false
        }

        return config
    },
}
```

When I try to run my script `npm run build:development` which in `package.json` represents:

```json
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf .next",
    "dev": "next dev",
    "export": "next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "build:development": "next build && npm run export && npm run rss:development",
    "build": "next build && npm run export && npm run rss",
    "rss:development": "node ./.next/server/scripts/build-rss.js",
    "rss": "node ./.next/serverless/scripts/build-rss.js"
}
```

It throws an error saying:

> Error: Cannot find module '../../webpack-runtime.js'

But I checked. The file does exist.

The blunder is this used to work earlier. Probably few versions ago when my other project used the same combination.

I have made a complete reproduction showcasing the error → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/next-script-rss-error

Just clone it, install it & try the script `npm run build:development` in the terminal to see the error.

Comment: `.next` directory is not present in your repo. also, that file `webpack-runtime.js` is being located in `.next/serverless` directory. when you're running the script, try `process.cwd()` to know the context directory from where script is being executed.

Comment: @boxdox `.next` gets created when you run `next build` & I have ignored it specifically in `.gitignore` so its not in the repo but exists locally. It only gets on `.next/serverless` on Vercel but on development it generates on `.next/server`. I'll try your `process.cwd()` suggestion but would love to know if you have anymore suggestions :)

Comment: @boxdox just tryied `process.cwd()` but it throws error before even running `build-rss.js`. Notice, how the entire file is empty & it still doesn't work. I did try with content in the file but nope it doesn't work either.

Comment: i don't have much experience with `nextjs`, but usually this issue is because how you call the file, and how does it's directory context change. mostly either it's looking in the wrong directory, or the required file is being generated after the script has finished

Comment: @boxdox ah this used to work previously so not sure what's the problem now haha. i'll take a look around though, thanks :)

Comment: Why can't the rss page be part of NextJS project itself? Why do you want a special script to render it?

Comment: @vijayst because I like separating post-scripts from the actual project. RSS, Sitemap, Image Optimizations, or even OG Image builders are things I'd like to add but putting it in the main project is useless as these things are only applied once after a post is published so I separate them. Ideally, I can put RSS in `index.tsx` & it will work but I'm not sure why this isn't working when it used to work earlier.

Comment: What I don't get is can't you just use ````config.entry.push(newEntry````, instead of all that async jazz.  Also why are you trying to run it as an individual script when you've added it to webpack bundle entries, in which case it'll be part of the webpack server bundle.

Comment: @Matriarx because I need to get whatever is in `originalEntry`. Idk what is in there but I copied from another repo & it used to work. It's an individual script because I only need to run it once on the server deployment. Like I said above, some things like RSS generator, Sitemap generator, OG Image generator or Image Optimizations are 1 time things which can be run post-script after everything is generated.

Comment: I don't think you need to get it that way (maybe I'm incorrect) but I just use ````entry.push```` on my own webpack (nextjs will certainly have something in there by default so you can just push to it).  And other than that, I understand why you "want" to use a single file, I'm telling you that webpack is outputting it to a single bundled server file (it will include your code inside all the other entry includes), the single file that you think exists will never exist unless it's chunk loaded and specifically outputted as a separate file.

Comment: @Matriarx can you post your code for reference on a gist or something or answer below. i got what you are saying but i can `ls` & `cat` the file to see its contents which is why its so confusing to me & this was already working on my previous project 2-3 months back so im confused. it still works if u check https://github.com/tailwindlabs/blog.tailwindcss.com

Comment: you better return to documents , module not found so it one of two conditions, either there is problem with module file itself , or there is version conflict and you need to use older stable version , contact the package developers  https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Answer (score 1):

Based on our conversation:

```
entry: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'path/to/file')
```

That's what a webpack entry looks like.  It can also be an array or an object:

```
entry: [
  path.join(__dirname, '..', 'path/to/file'),
  // other entries here
]
```

Whereas you're already getting the whole webpack config:

```
webpack: (config, options)
```

So doing:

```
const originalEntry = config.entry

config.entry = async () => {
  const entries = { ...(await originalEntry()) }
  entries['./scripts/build-rss'] = './scripts/build-rss.js'
  return entries
}
```

Makes no sense to me if you can just do:

```
config.entry.push('./scripts/build-rss')
// config.entry['./scripts/build-rss'] = './scripts/build-rss.js'
```

Unless I miss something with how nextjs is loading the webpack config.

Even then I'd suggest that you use `path.join` in order to ensure it's loaded to the correct location, because that relative root will execute from wherever webpack is compiled from.

Along with that in your first project you used nextjs v10 and now you're using nextjs v11, which has an upgrade from webpack 4 to 5, which is a major upgrade.  I don't know the details, I can only speculate, but under no conditions should you assume that "because your previous project was working this one should using the same stuff", it won't necessarily (especially not in this case).

The first intuitive thing I thought was that webpack should by default bundle everything to a single output file, unless the configuration for that was changed by nextjs (I don't know).  So using a script you added to entries didn't make sense to me, because it wouldn't exist.  But you're saying that it does exist so I can only assume that webpack is configured to do code splitting and outputs each entry to a different file.  In which case I have no idea.  As far as I'm aware in webpack 5 (I don't know about webpack 4) code splitting is disabled in dev and enabled in production so your problem is likely a discrepancy between dev and production.

Perhaps the last thing you can try is to change your `!options.dev`, because right now you're only adding that script when it's production but you're trying to run the script using development.

If you really just have to get it working you can downgrade your nextjs to the previous version you were using (v10), even though that's not really a solution.

Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I get an error `TypeError: config.entry.push is not a function` when I use `push`

Comment: Try the second example I commented out, perhaps it's an object.

Comment: This time I get the original error I got `Error: Cannot find module '../../webpack-runtime.js'` so looks like both solutions lead to the same problem. Something definitely changed in either Next.js or Webpack I think :(

Comment: No both solutions don't lead to the same problem, now you've successfully removed all that unnecessary and irrelevant async stuff and just directly assigned the entry value.  Now you can deal with your main problem which I addressed in the rest of my answer.

Comment: Still doesn't work. I tried removing `options.dev` as well as removing the whole `if` statement but no luck. I think `next build` does run production build. I've just named my scripts `npm run build:development` as Vercel has the folder name `.serverless` on server  & its `.server` locally so I'm not sure if that's the problem. I've asked the Webpack creator who now works in Next.js as well so he most probably knows the answer & hopefully answers. Thanks for your help though. I'll try downgrading in the meantime to see if it works & open an issue if it's really a bug :)

Comment: Alright.  Hope you figure it out.  Comment here if you do, I'm interested to know what it is causing it.

Comment: Yeah, I found it works on Next v10 so opened an issue https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/28111

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are still looking for an answer, but simply changing the webpack entry as follows seems to have fixed the problem.

```js
entries['scripts/build-rss'] = './scripts/build-rss.js';
// instead of entries['./scripts/build-rss']
```

Comment: i'll accept this when i check it for myself but as i said on the github issue (yes, same guy), `./` was working on previous next versions :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Error! I deleted the `.next` Folder and did an `npm run dev`, It started to work for me!

Comment: this only worked bcz in recent versions, the error has been fixed :)

Comment: Ohh Glad that it did, but still I have to do did frequently, No Idea Why this is happening